# SQL Calculations with HH:MM:SS

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have a column that comes into my SQL database as a `varchar(10)`, but looks like HH:MM:SS. The column name is runTime.

I need to convert that column to seconds and do some calculations with it and another colunm called totalItems.  totalItems is an `int` data type.  An example of one calculation would be:

```
totalItems/runTime
```

So, it appears as though I need to convert runTime to a decimal, and then use it in the calculation, but when I can't do that without first converting the time to seconds, or I get an error (due to the ":").

So, how can I possibly convert the sessionRunTime into seconds first, and then convert those seconds to a decimal data type, then do the calculation from there?  One example might be 59222 totalItems and 04:15:17 for runTime.

If there's a better way to handle this, I'm certainly open to that as well.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So long as the hours portion doesn't match or exceed 24, you can [`convert`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) to a datetime and use the [built in functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms189794%28v=sql.90%29) to work out how long the time is in seconds:

```
select DATEDIFF(second,'00:00:00',CONVERT(datetime,'04:15:17'))

15317
```

If you need to do maths with this result, and the other value is an `int`, then multiple one or other of the values by `1.0` to force the maths to be done as `float`s, if that's required.

Answer (score 0):

You can cast to `datetime` and use [datediff](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) to convert your string to seconds.

```
select datediff(second, 0, cast('04:15:17' as datetime))
```

Result:

```
15317
```